# Alignment Not working on firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

vertical and horizontal alignment and height percentage not working correctly in firefox Although it works fine on IE and Chrome 
i set hight and width to 100% in html and body

```
html,body { heigh:100% ; width:100% }
```

and i tried all possible solutions like `text-align: -moz-center; display:block;`
and here's my code

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width: 100%; height: 93%;">
    <tr style="height: 42px; width: 100%">
        <td style="width: 80px; background-image: url(Images/logo.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;
            height: 42px;">
        </td>
        <td style="height: 42px">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center" valign="middle">
        <td style="height: 196px;" align="center" valign="middle">
            <table class="partTable" style="padding-bottom: 20px">
           <tr>
                    <td align="center" style="font-size: xx-large; font-family: Arial Black; color: #C11B17">
                        <span>
                            <%=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppName"]%>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table border="0" style="text-align: -moz-center; vertical-align: middle; display: block;
                margin: 0 auto;">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="middle" class="partHolder" style="width: 314px; height: 201px;">
                 --Content
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </tr>
```

notice: the table doesn't take the 93% of the page. it takes like an auto .and thats happened when I put `<!DOCTYPE html>` before html tag

Comment: `margin:0px auto` make your table centered. Btw [height 93%](http://jsfiddle.net/A8yVa/1/) works fine for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use style `margin:0 auto` to center your table.
2. Make sure all containers for table are height: 100%;
   For example:

   - [this will work](http://jsfiddle.net/A8yVa/1/)
   - [this won't work](http://jsfiddle.net/A8yVa/2/) - and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/A8yVa/2/) is the fix

And you have some misconvenience in your code:

```
<tr style="height: 42px; width: 100%">
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^ this is ok
   </tr>
   <tr align="center" valign="middle">
       <td style="height: 196px;">
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
                 This is wrong. you should 
                 remove it to make table auto-risze. 
                 And you should use `height` only to <tr>
```

> it takes like an auto .and thats happened when I put 
>   before html tag

Firefox simply goes mad if you use `height:93%` and then you use `height:42px`,`height:196px` for rows. I believe Firefox is using more strict method to render HTML+CSS when you use `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag

Also.. don't use `text-align` for `table`,`tr` - because they doesn't contains any text. Use it only for `td`

Comment: the problem of height:93% and vertical alignment solved but horizontal alignment still.thanks for your reply

Comment: i want to align first tr to left and the second one to center

Comment: `<td style="text-align:left;">`, `<td style="text-align:center;">`. Never use `text-align` for `<tr>`, `<table>`

Comment: <tr valign="middle">
            <td valign="middle" style="text-align:center;">
              </td>
        </tr> there are 2 tables inside td like in question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15810/discussion-between-kareem-mouneir-and-peter-szymkowski)